# Probablity of finding different monday and sunday

Tags: probability

Choose a number $n$ uniformly at random from the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, 100\}$. Choose one of the first seven days of the year 2014 at random and consider $n$ consecutive days starting from the chosen day. What is the probability that among the chosen $n$ days, the number of Sundays is different from the number of Mondays?

This is question which came in well know KVPY exam 2014.

What is going to be sample space ? $100$ ? or do we need to group it.